# Flip Horizontal CSS and reverse it with JavaScript based on RTL Direction

Tags: javascript, css, right-to-left

I'm going to change LTR direction of whole web page to RTL direction, the easiest way it's flip horizontal css and then add class to each element section of page to make it as RTL direction. Here is my CSS code:

```
.rtl {
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
-ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}

<body class="rtl">
```

then we need to add rtl class to each element of page to make it as real RTL, for example:

```
<div class="rtl">Text Here</div>  => Real RTL Direction
```

now here is my question:

> How to reverse whole of body class to RTL direction and flip horizontal using javascript ?

If there's any solution to change direction of body to RTL with JavaScript, then no need to add class of flip horizontal to each section of website. 
Currently the only way to change direction is that we add class to each texts sections and image sections elements fiv, span, p, and etc

I tried HTML direction RTL and body RTL, but not working, I believe if we will be able to force body direction to RTL and flip horizontal then it can be solved.

I highly appreciate any comment and idea in this question.

Comment: I'm confused, could you please share an image what you are trying to achieve? Note that `direction` and *flipping horizontal* are different things...

Comment: It's clear, if we use css to flip, then it's like a mirror, but you can't read texts cause it's flipped, it's not RTL, you need to flip it again based on class.

Answer (score 3):

It works when i force body to show either `dir=rtl` or `dir=ltr`. And for `flip`, i use your css and put `*` as the selector too select all element. check this out:

```js
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
b.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
/* b.setAttribute("dir", "ltr"); */
console.log(b);
```

```html
<h1> Hello world </h1>
<div> Text Here</div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

More about this: [Css Tricks on text direction](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)

in case you want to flip all element can add this:

```
* {
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
-ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}
```

But if you means: from **Hello world** you want it to appear as **dlrow olleH**
you can try this one:

```js
var ns = document.body.childNodes;
ns.forEach(function(elm) {
  if (elm.innerText && elm.nodeName !== "SCRIPT") {
    //set array of char then re-arrange char
    var arr = elm.innerText.split(''),
      temp = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = x = arr.length - 1; i <= l; i++, x--) {
      temp[i] = arr[x];
    }
    elm.innerText = temp.join('')
  }
})
```

```html
<h1> Hello world </h1>
<div>Text Here</div>
<p>lorem ipsum<span> span </span>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Please, Provide the snippet based on css code in above and based on mentioned question

Comment: So now as you can see, it's just flipped, it's not RTL. you can't read Hello world! Hope you now understand what's the question!

Comment: Unfortunately i still dont understand the question. Sorry. If you want it to be readable but in RTL direction. why don't just remove the `flip-css`-thing?
aka just use RTL without flip
or maybe better if you can try to upload image what you want to achieve, (in case I am not the only who don't understand)

regards

Comment: ok please check updated answer. maybe that is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

As you are using flipH filter.

```js
$(document).on("click","html",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("flipX");
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rebeccapurple, skyblue);
  color: white;
}

.flipX {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
          transform: scaleX(-1);
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  -webkit-filter: FlipH;
          filter: FlipH;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Page Title</h1>
<p>Click to flip...</p>
```