# display text from right to left

Tags: html, css

I'm using this css to set the elements position from right to left

```
body
{
  background-color: white !important;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

But the text still starts from left to right  I meam It shows `"Hello"` I need to show `"olleH"` , how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this:

```css
body {
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  text in right-to-left language
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add something like this:

```
body {
      unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
      direction:rtl;
    }
```

Comment: If it didnt work you can try with rotating text like in this case:                          `div {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}` <-- this rotate entire text, but this one flip each letter backwards --> `div {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
}`

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways this could happen. See the snippet below,search your css for and remove the problematic code (The way you wrote the reverse words it seems you are having `transform: rotateY` effecting the element).

```css
body {
  direction:rtl;
}
.reverse{
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
.rotateY{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
Reverse: <div class="reverse">123456</div>
Rotate: <div class="rotateY">123456</div>
Normal: <div>123456</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample pen: https://codepen.io/tains/pen/BXopEP?editors=1100

PS: I have this line because children tag don't inherit.

```
* {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779933/flip-horizontal-css-and-reverse-it-with-javascript-based-on-rtl-direction) 
use ScaleX: (-1)

```
<head>
<style>
   body {
   direction: rtl;
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
   -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
   filter: fliph; /*IE*/
 }
</style>
</head>

<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use float or absolute, rtl will not work.It only works when element's display is flex or inline-block.If you want to use rtl,see https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss/